# Reward always Zero

Tags: mining, block-reward, monero-forks, helium-hydra

Again I need your help. I created a fork of Monero. In the first version I only changed the crypto name, but all other values are the same as Monero. My problem is, I found around 300 blocks, but the reward is always zero. My wallet has its balance and unlocked balance as Zero. Could you help me? What did I do wrong? Thank you!!

Comment: Nobody can tell you what you did wrong without seeing your code. You clearly changed more than just the name. Did you change the pre tail emission supply or emission curve? Does your payout address for mining rewards match the address of the balance you are checking?

Comment: Thank you Jun Li...I will fork again and begin from the start again...Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bug was recently fixed in Monero, which causes wallets created on chains with very low amount of blocks to mistakenly skip blocks. This will be corrected in the coming release, and is already fixed in Monero master, so if you update and recreate your steps, it should now work. You can also use your existing wallet by running "set refresh-from-block-height 0" in monero-wallet-cli after updating.

See https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/2542 for the fix.